# How to get all matched parts to regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, sequencematcher

I have to parse a String in 3 stages. Only first stage works, in 2 and 3 stage matcher.groupCount() returns 0 - which means it found nothing. I was testing my regex in online tester and it was just fine. But here it doesn't work. So the question is maybe I miss something or regex has mistake in it?

```
String rawText = "ashjdajsdg:[requiredPartForFirstPattern]}asdassdasd";
Pattern firstPattern = Pattern.compile("(:\\[)(.*?)(\\]})");
List<String> firstList = parseContent(rawText, firstPattern);
```

After execution firstList should contain only one value (in this case): "requiredPartForFirstPattern" (could be any char or any char sequence).

Now I am iterating all the values in the firstList and checking them with 2 pattern:

All values in firstList will have such form: "[someText1],[someText2],[someText3]".

```
String rawText = "[someText1],[someText2],[someText3]"; 
Pattern secondPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[([^]]*)\\])");
List<String> secondList = parseContent(rawText, secondPattern);
```

After execution secondList should contain this values (in this case): "someText1","someText2","someText3".

And finally the third stage. I iterate all values in secondList and check them with 3 pattern. All values in secondList will have such form:
"'someValue1','someValue2'".

```
String rawText = "'someValue1','someValue2'";
Pattern thirdPattern = Pattern.compile("('(.*?)')");
List<String> thirdList = parseContent(rawText, secondPattern);
```

After execution secondList should contain this values (in this case): "someValue1","someValue2".

My parseContent method:

```
    private List<String> parseContent(String content, Pattern pattern) {
        List<String> matchedList = new LinkedList<>();

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            for(int matchIndex = 0; matchIndex < matcher.groupCount(); ++matchIndex) {
                matchedList.add(matcher.group(matchIndex));
            }
        }
        return matchedList;
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question/problem?

Comment: Only first stage works, in 2 and 3 stage matcher.groupCount() returns 0 - which means it found nothing. I was testing my regex in online tester and it was just fine. But here it doesn't work. So the question is maybe I miss something or regex has mistake in it?

Comment: Can you post this as part of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should have while (matcher.find()) instead of an if-statement.

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    for(int matchIndex = 0; matchIndex < matcher.groupCount(); ++matchIndex) {
        matchedList.add(matcher.group(matchIndex));
    }
}
```

I've replaced above code with this one:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    matchedList.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Works fine, ty for help.

Comment: It says I can do that in 2 days.

Comment: @Pshemo I am not getting all matched values using same matcher... Getting 1 less record in the matched one... using while as you mentioned ... WOuld you please let me know why it is happening

Comment: @Aakriti.G I can't help without seeing example which will let me reproduce your problem. Post data which you are parsing, regex which you are using, expected result and actual result. You can do it by asking separate question (when you are done feel free to ping me here with link to it).